# how to configure scope model driven interceptor in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, struts

how to configure scope model driven interceptor in struts2?

I'm trying to implement scope model driven interceptor in my application, but I'm getting an error.

Following is the error:

```
Caused by: Attribute "class" must be declared for element type "interceptor-ref".
```

Struts.xml code:

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="dwsCreate" method="dwsCreate" class="com.struts.action.DispatchUserAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="scoped-model-driven">
            <param name="scope">session</param>  
            <param name="name">objWorksheetActionForm</param>  
            <param name="className">com.struts.actionform.WorksheetActionForm1</param>  
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <result name="dwsCreate">/jsp/dwsV2/dwsCreate.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/SessionExpired.jsp</result>
    </action>


</package>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want model driven, even scoped to session how it will solve your problems?

Comment: @RomanC - I need to pass the object to another action. How can I configure? What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Such interceptor name is unknown by the default configuration.

Comment: @RomanC - Can you please correct me?

Comment: Are you using struts1 plugin for your action forms?

Comment: @RomanC - No. I do not know about this plugin. Can you please enlighten  me.

Comment: The plugin is to use struts1 actions and forms as is used in struts1, but run in struts2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="scopedModelDriven.scope">session</param>
    <param name="scopedModelDriven.name">objWorksheetActionForm</param>
<param name="scopedModelDriven.className">com.struts.actionform.WorksheetActionForm1</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

One more thing which is important and I didn't found anywhere else:

When you try to implement ScopedModelDriven Interceptor, do not write(like given below) in Action class

```
WorksheetActionForm1 obj = new WorksheetActionForm1();
```

It creates a new object and over writes the session values.
Instead, create a null object.

```
WorksheetActionForm1 obj = null;
```

When the bean is persisted in session, it copies the properties to the bean object from the stack.

Comment: I am having some difficulties configuring scope model driven interceptor. I wanted all my model to be in session scope, how do I configure the interceptor for all forms?